# ionic 3 native HTTP does not let me access JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I am using ionic 3 native HTTP to do a POST request to my backend server which returns JSON data but when I try to access the object from the variable I get an error:

> [ts] Property 'InRepair' does not exist on type '{}'.
>   any

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

I made my POST request function a provider and here is the code for that

HttpProvider.ts

```
    import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';

@Injectable()
export class TekItapiProvider {
apiURL = 'myAPISeverURL';

constructor(private http: HTTP) {
}

  doPost(url, data) {
    var endpointURL = this.apiURL + url;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      this.http.post(endpointURL, data, this.headers)
        .then(data => {
          resolve(data.data);
        })

        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error.status);
          reject(error);
        })
    })
  }

}
```

This is where it is being called and where I try to access the object. In status I can access `.completed` because it gives me the error:  [ts] Property 'InRepair' does not exist on type '{}'.
any

request.ts

```
this.httpProvider.doPost(myURL, '')
.then((status) => {
     if (status.completed == 'Yes') {

     }
     },(err) => {

     })
```

Do you guys know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: which method throws error?

Comment: Why don't you use default angular `HTTP` module?

Comment: inside the this.httpProvider.doPost throws the error.  the .completed object of status if exactly where the error is.

Comment: I dont use the regular HTTP module because I need the background threading of the native one so when users close their screens it does not stop the Http requests

Comment: and just to clarify further the data object is: data: {data: {completed: true} }.  So data.data.completed should work